# Is the `new` keyword the only way to automatically set the `constructor` property when constructing objects?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I'm currently using `Object.create()` to construct objects like so:

```js
const Tab = ({id, windowId}) => Object.assign(Object.create(Tab.prototype), {id, windowId})

Tab.prototype = {
  constructor: Tab,
  toString: function() {
    return `${this.constructor.name} ${JSON.stringify(Object.values(this))}`
  }
}
```

One of the goals is to avoid using the `new` keyword, so that I can use the constructor function, for example, like this: `[{id: 1, windowId: 2}].map(Tab)` (same as it's possible with native constructors like `String`; for example, `[1,2,3].map(String)` works). The problem is that it's not nice to have to define the constructor property manually, so is there some way to get around it and have the constructor set automatically, like with the `new` keyword, while still using `Object.create()`?

**Update** Fixed version based on answers:

```
const Tab = function({id, windowId}) {
  return Object.assign(Object.create(Tab.prototype), {id, windowId})
}

Object.assign(Tab.prototype, {
  toString: function() {
    return `${this.constructor.name} ${JSON.stringify(Object.values(this))}`
  }
})
```

Comment: Note that one problem you're going to have is that (as far as I know) that arrow function is not going to have a "name" property (or it'll be `undefined` or something).

Comment: I'm targeting Chrome (extension), which supports inferred names on anonymous functions, so it works.

Comment: Oh OK. That's kind-of nice I guess.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why are you using `Tab.prototype` after all (as opposed to a separate object literal)?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, sorry. I'm using the prototype because it's shared between the created objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Oriol mentioned, the `prototype` and the `prototype.constructor` properties are assigned when the function is created. His solution still contains the `new` keyword though, which you seem to want to avoid.

**Arrow functions don't assign the constructor property**

Arrow functions however don't have a `prototype` or `prototype.constructor` property created automatically and they cannot be instantiated using the `new` keyword.

If you don't have a specific need to stick with an arrow function, I would recommend using a classic named function expression. Since chrome seems to infer names on anonymous functions, you might not need the name though.

**Overriding Tab.prototype overrides the constructor property as well**

The other reason why you don't keep the `.constructor` property, is because you are overriding the entire `Tab.prototype` when assigning an object to it. Instead, you could just assign the properties in a singular fashion:

```
const Tab = function Tab({id, windowId}) { return Object.assign(Object.create(Tab.prototype), {id, windowId}) };

Tab.prototype.toString = function() {
    return `${this.constructor.name} ${JSON.stringify(Object.values(this))}`
  }
};
```

Or you could use `Object.assign` to add the extra properties to `Tab.prototype`:

```
const Tab = function Tab({id, windowId}) { return Object.assign(Object.create(Tab.prototype), {id, windowId}) };

Object.assign(Tab.prototype, {
    toString() {
       return `${this.constructor.name} ${JSON.stringify(Object.values(this))}`
    }
});
```

And in case you are writing a publicly accessible function and want to forbid others to use the `new` operator on your function a well, you can use [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target) to stop this from happening:

```
const Tab = function Tab({id, windowId}) {
    if (new.target) {
        throw new Error(`${ this.constructor.name } is not a constructor`);
    }
    return Object.assign(Object.create(Tab.prototype), {id, windowId})
};

// ...
```

Comment: Thanks, my confusion was stemming from forgetting that arrow functions didn't have prototypes. I've updated the question with what I ended up using.

Comment: Don't forget Reflect.construct() either :)

Comment: That's true, although it is in many ways similar to the `new` operator (supporting the pseudo-classical inheritance paradigm). Unless of course the OP's reason for not using new are more technical.

Answer (score 4):

The [`new` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.2) does not create a `constructor` property. It just calls the [[[Construct]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2) internal method.

Instances don't have any `constructor` property by default. They only inherit it from their [[Prototype]], which is the `prototype` of the constructor.

The `prototype` and `constructor` properties are created only once, when you [create the function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2).

If you want to be able to call a constructor as a function, you can use

```
function Constructor() {
  if(this instanceof Constructor) {
    // Called as a constructor
    // ...
  } else {
    // Called as a function
    return new Constructor();
  }
}
```

This also allows you to implement different behaviors for each case, like with `String`, e.g.

```
typeof String(); // "string"
typeof new String(); // "object"`.
```

Comment: Might be worth to point out that constructors created via `class` *cannot* be called as a function.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather just avoid the `new` keyword entirely. Here's to hoping it will be made optional for the class syntax as well in ES7.

Comment: @ReinisI. You can use `var instance = Object.create(Constructor.prototype), ret = Constructor.call(instance); return Object(ret) === ret ? ret : instance;` instead of `new`. But why do you want to avoid `new`?

Comment: I'm actually not sure what you mean by that code example; how would that be better than the current way (updated in the question)? To quote Eric Eliott about the `new` keyword: "The `new` keyword violates both the substitution principle and the open / closed principle. It’s also destructive because it adds zero value to the language, and it couples all callers to the details of object instantiation."

Comment: @ReinisI. That code polyfills `new` / [[Construct]]. The full code would be https://jsfiddle.net/aho9chqx/

Comment: I understand what it does, the question is why.